# code igniter pagination with sort options

Tags: sorting, codeigniter, pagination

I'm not sure if what I'm about to ask is possible or not.. I'm thinking probably not but I thought I would ask anyways.

Is there any way to reset the pagination?

I've got a page with has pagination and sort option on it. Everything works fine but when one of the sort options is changed I would like to send the user back to the first page.

(I'm pretty sure the way I'm doing this isn't at all the best way to get the result I want so if you have any suggestions for improvements please feel free.)

```
        $array =  explode ("_",$this->uri->segment(4));

        if(count($array) > 1){
            $search_id = $array[1];
            $start = $this->uri->segment(5);
            $uri_segment = 5;
        }else{
            $start = $this->uri->segment(4);
            $uri_segment = 4;
            $search_id = null;
        }
$config['per_page'] = $this->settings['PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE'];

$config['total_rows'] = $this->categories_model->get_num_rows($cat_id , $search_type, $search_data);

$query = $this->categories_model->get_category_pages($cat_id, $new_limit, $new_sort, $search_id, $start, $this->settings['CATEGORY_ORDER'], $search_type, $search_data,  $config['total_rows']))

$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'index.php/categories/view/' . $cat_id ."/" . $search_string ;

 $config['uri_segment'] = $uri_segment;

 //Congig settings for pagination
 $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination" style= "clear:both;">';
 $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

 //Initialise pagination
 $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: are you using a table to display the data on the page ?

Comment: No I'm not I'm just looping through each of the results and echoing them to the page.

Comment: I would suggest displaying the data in a table (styled with css, it won't even look like a table to the end user!), and then leveraging jQuery dataTables plugin to do sorting, search, pagination. The plugin supports server side pagination so your code is still reusable to some extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may keep a default sorting in controller which will not show in url.so sorting will not back to the first page.

a sample

```
class Post extends Jewelery_Controller {

public function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('Prime_model');
 }

  public function index($ordr_by = 'post_title', $sortr = 'ASC') {

  if ($this->uri->segment(6)) {
     $data['segment'] = $this->uri->segment(6);
  } else {
     $data['segment'] = 0;
  }

  if ($this->uri->segment(4)) {
     $ordr_by = $this->uri->segment(4);
  }

  if ($this->uri->segment(5)) {
     $sortr = $this->uri->segment(5);
  }

  $data['title'] = 'All Posts';
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'admin/post/index/' . $ordr_by . '/' . $sortr;
  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';
  $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
  $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
  $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
  $config['uri_segment'] = 6;
  $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->get('jewel_posts')->num_rows();
  $config['per_page'] = 10;
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);


  $data['post_info'] = $this->Prime_model->master_join('jewel_posts', 'jewel_jewelry_type', 'jewel_posts.jewelry_type = jewel_jewelry_type.jewelry_type_id', 'left', FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, $ordr_by, $sortr, $config['per_page'], $data['segment']);
  $this->load->view('admin/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('admin/post/index');
  $this->load->view('admin/footer');
}
```